Why am I getting "InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." only when using `-Parallel`?
I am using Powershell version 7.4.6
And I don't understand this behaviour.
I have a regular expression
$r = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex "a+"

and when I run it
( 'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b' ) | ForEach-Object { $r.isMatch( $_ ) }

I get the expected:
True
True
True
False 

but if I try to run it with -Parallel like:
    ( 'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b' ) | ForEach-Object -Parallel { $r.isMatch( $_ ) }

I surprisingly get:
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Why

-Parallel starts new threads, and $r isn't accessible from any of the new threads.

This question has the same solution as the "duplicate" but IMHO it's a different question due to a different error message, and is worth keeping for the search indexability of it.

You will need to use the using: scope modifier to pass-in the Regex instance to the parallel scope, it's also required to enclose the expression in parentheses due to a parsing error:
$r = [regex]::new("a+")
'a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b' | ForEach-Object -Parallel { ($using:r).IsMatch($_) }

